# Não estou conseguindo enviar um POST para o PHP pelo fetch do Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, post, get, fetch

#### Estou tentando enviar um POST para o PHP usando o fetch, o código está assim:

```html
<button onclick="fnConsultarDadosPost()">Consultar com POST</button>
<button onclick="fnConsultarDadosGet()">Consultar com GET</button>
```

```js
fnConsultarDadosPost = () => {
    const nome = document.querySelector('#nome').value

    fetch('dados.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: nome,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'plain/text'
        }
    })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => fnExibirResultado(res))
}

fnConsultarDadosGet = () => {
    const nome = document.querySelector('#nome').value

    fetch(`dados.php?nome=${nome}`)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => fnExibirResultado(res))
}

fnExibirResultado = (dados) => {
    document.querySelector('#mensagem').innerHTML = dados
}
```

#### Meu backend está assim:

```php
// Dei um var_dump do $_POST e ele retornou NULL
var_dump($_POST);

if ($_GET) {
    $nome = $_GET['nome'];

    echo "Conteúdo recebido por GET com sucesso! Seu nome é $nome";
} else if ($_POST) {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

    echo "Conteúdo recebido por POST com sucesso! Seu nome é $nome";
}
```

#### Conclusão:

Quando eu uso o **GET**, ele me retorna certinho, mas quando eu uso o **POST** ele nem chega no PHP. Estou esquecendo de algo na sintaxe do **POST**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `$_POST` do PHP pressupõe `chave=valor` no `body`, ou então uma requisição multipart. No primeiro caso precisa usar o tipo `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, no segundo `multipart/form-data`.

Você está mandando só o valor no body. Ou acerta o POST ou recupera com o `php://input`.

Veja a diferença com estas linhas:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

e

```
const nome = 'nome=' + document.querySelector('#nome').value
//           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Clique em executar:

```js
fnConsultarDadosPost = () => {
    const nome = 'nome=' + document.querySelector('#nome').value

    fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: nome,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => fnExibirResultado(res))
}

fnConsultarDadosGet = () => {
    const nome = document.querySelector('#nome').value

    fetch(`https://httpbin.org/get?nome=${nome}`)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => fnExibirResultado(res))
}

fnExibirResultado = (dados) => {
    document.querySelector('#mensagem').innerHTML = dados
}
```

```html
<input id="nome" value="biriba">
<button onclick="fnConsultarDadosPost()">Consultar com POST</button>
<button onclick="fnConsultarDadosGet()">Consultar com GET</button>

<pre id="mensagem"></pre>
```

Ou, do lado do PHP vai ter que fazer algo assim:

```
$hndl = fopen("php://input", "r");
$data = fread($hndl, 1024); // Talvez um loop se a informação for longa
```

Comment: Muito interessante! Você ajudou muitas pessoas hoje meu amigo, obrigado por compartilhar esse conhecimento. Qual o mais indicado nesses casos? Usar essa concatenação ali mesmo no javascript ou recuperar no PHP como você explicou?

Comment: Em princípio os dois funcionam, e não muda muita coisa no mecanismo de envio. Não tem "melhor", tem que ver qual fica melhor no contexto em que vai usar.