# Javascript passar mais de um parametro atraves do fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

No link abaixo, consegui como enviar um parametro atraves do fetch pelo body, mas preciso enviar mais de um, por exemplo, valores de um formulario.

Preciso de um exemplo, usando POST para enviar atraves do body, por exemplo:
id: 1234, nome: Teste, tipo: pagamento etc, algo assim.

Agradeço, ajuda.

[Não estou conseguindo enviar um POST para o PHP pelo fetch do Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/438946/n%C3%A3o-estou-conseguindo-enviar-um-post-para-o-php-pelo-fetch-do-javascript)

```
fnConsultarDadosPost = () => {
    const nome = document.querySelector('#nome').value

    fetch('dados.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: nome,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'plain/text'
        }
    })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => fnExibirResultado(res))
}


fnExibirResultado = (dados) => {
    document.querySelector('#mensagem').innerHTML = dados
}
```

Comment: Desculpe gostaria de acrescentar que estou tentando passar para uma pagina PHP.
Conseguindo passar os dados, como faço para recebe-los no PHP.
Obrigado.

Comment: edite sua pergunta e coloque essa informação lá ao invés de adicionar um comentário

Answer (score 4):

Você pode criar um objeto com os valores e passar no `body`, assim por exemplo:

```
var dados = {
   id: 1234, 
   nome: "Teste", 
   tipo: "pagamento"
};


fetch('dados.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(dados),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
```

O `JSON.stringify` vai serializar seu objeto com os dados e passar como parâmetro. Note que como está sendo passado um `JSON`, o `header` também deve ter esse valor.

Comment: Ricardo, como o AP está utilizando PHP, não seria melhor utilizar o _Content-Type_ `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ao invés de `application/json`? Pergunto porque a superglobal `$_POST` já suporta _urlencoded_ nativamente, o que não acontece com o _json_... [Continuação desta pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/494083/como-pegar-valores-de-um-objeto-passado-pelo-fetch-pelo-php#comment917968_494083)

Comment: olá Luis. Sim seria possível, mas não do jeito que está na pergunta, passando um objeto, precisaria postar todo o form, por exemplo passando do `body` do `fetch` algo assim: `body: new FormData($(form))`, dessa forma iria receber o form e poderia sim ler os valores usando o `$_POST`. Se mudar o content passando um objeto json, deve dar um erro de *Bad Request*, mas precisaria fazer um teste para confirmar