# Como pegar valores de um objeto passado pelo fetch pelo PHP

Tags: php, fetch

```
var dados = {
   id: 1234, 
   nome: "Teste", 
   tipo: "pagamento"
};


fetch('dados.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(dados),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
```

Recebi essa ajuda de como passar dados através do `fetch`. Minha dúvida é como obter esses valores no PHP. Tentei `print_r(dados)`, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Você está enviando os dados com _Content-Type_ `application/json`. Como o PHP aceita, por padrão, dados em formato _urlencoded_, não seria mais prudente os enviar neste formato?

Comment: Veja **[aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/494072/69296)** como enviar campos utilizando _Content-Type_ **_urlencoded_** utilizando a API `fetch`. Se você está utilizando PHP, não há porque enviar em formato JSON, uma vez que _urlencoded_ é suportado **nativamente** pela superglobal [`$_POST`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php).

Answer (score -2):

Faz o seguinte, no php deixa assim:

```
$result = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo json_encode($result);

e no js deixa assim:

const form = {
    a: "Teste",
    b: 50000,
  };

 fetch(`url`, {
    headers: {
       Accept: "application/json",
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(form),
  })
    .then((r) => r.json())
    .then((r) => {
      console.log(r);
    });
```